# Pivotar un dataframe sobre dos columnas con Python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe del cual necesito pivotar dos columnas sobre la columna "valor", y las dos columnas son "etiqueta" y "fechaValor". La etiqueta indica el tipo de sensórica que se tiene asociado un registro en la columna "valor", y la "fechaValor" indica cuando se ha registrado.

Necesito que para cada tipo de etiqueta también se pivote su "fechaValor" correspondiente. Solo consigo pivotar sobre "valor".

El dataframe original es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente (creo el dataframe también, para que podáis reproducirlo):

```
df_Datos = pd.DataFrame({'idDCL': ['660IAT', '660IAT', '660IAT', '660IAT', '660IAT', '660IAT'],
                   'idCDU': ['AAF-653', 'AAF-653', 'AAF-653', 'AAF-653', 'AAF-653', 'AAF-653'],
                   'etiqueta': ['COOL.Temperatura', 'COOL.Humedad',  'COOL.Acelerometro', 'COOL.Luz', 'COOL.latitud', 'COOL.longitud'],
                   'valor': [239.954, 970.797, 0.987659, 0.0, 768.425, 124.995],
                   'fechaValor': ['06/11/2022  22:37:00', '06/11/2022  22:37:00', '06/11/2022  22:37:00', '06/11/2022  22:37:00', '06/11/2022  22:37:00', '06/11/2022  22:37:00']})

df_Datos = df_Datos.pivot_table(index=['idCDU', 'fechaValor'], columns='etiqueta', values='valor').reset_index()
df_Datos.columns.etiqueta = ''

df_Datos.head()
```

El resultado esperado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema y sería mejor que agregaras algunas filas de tus `dataset` como texto en la pregunta también.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato cierto, perdona! he metido el resultado que espero y unas líneas del dataframe inicial